# Como recorrer por columnas y contar en pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo esta matriz que la construyo a partir de un csv y lo que requiero es poder contar si un user ha votado por un item y poder ir recorriendo las columnas para ir sacando estos valores.
En la de la salida esta el ejemplo en la columna que inicia quiero ir contando que un usuario haya votado por un ítem de 1 a 5 y pasar a la siguiente columna a si sucesivamente.

Tal vez me podrían más o menos ayudar con alguna idea por favor.

```
def read_data():
    path_file = './data.csv'
    data = pd.read_csv(path_file, delimiter=';')
    num_rating = len(data['rating'].unique())
    alpha = 0.01
    min_rating = data['rating'].min()
    max_rating = data['rating'].max()
    # create matrix
    rating_matrix = data.pivot_table(index='user',
                                     columns='item',
                                     values='rating',
                                     fill_value=0)
    dt = pd.DataFrame(rating_matrix)
    print(dt)
```

Salida:

```
item  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
user                           
1     0  1  2  2  5  0  4  3  5
2     1  5  3  0  2  3  4  3  0
3     1  1  2  0  2  4  4  5  0
4     3  2  2  3  0  1  3  2  0
5     5  1  5  5  4  4  5  2  0
```

Comment: lo siento no he entendido bien tu problema

Comment: cada columna representa el numero de votos del usuario, verdad?

Comment: Hola, si eso mismo representa y quiero contar por cada columna de 1 a 5 si ha votado o no.

Comment: quieres obtener el total de votos?

Comment: Quiero obtener lo siguiente ejemplo: Columna 1 hay 0 1 1 3 5 entonces quiero obtener cuantas veces votaron por 1 en este caso hay 2 luego ver cuantas veces votaron por 2.. Hasta llegar al 5 en este caso 5 hay 1 y luego pasar a la siguiente columna que es 1 5 1 2 1 y hacer lo mismo cuantas veces votaron por 1 hay 3 por 2 hay 1 y así hasta llegar al final de la columnas.

Comment: entonces quieres saber el total de votos por *categoria* (1,2,3,4,..)?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que deseas es una tabla de frecuencia para cada valor, en pandas la puedes obtener con `df.value_counts()` así:

*Tomando el ejemplo de Christian

```py
#%% importar
import pandas as pd
#%%replicando tu dataframe
cols = ['val1','val2','val3','val4','val5','val6','val7','val8','val9']
data = [                           
[0,1,2,2,5,0,4,3,5],
[1,5,3,0,2,3,4,3,0],
[1,1,2,0,2,4,4,5,0],
[3,2,2,3,0,1,3,2,0],
[5,1,5,5,4,4,5,2,0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols,index=range(5))

result=df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).fillna(0)

print(result)
```

output:

```
   val1  val2  val3  val4  val5  val6  val7  val8  val9
0   1.0   0.0   0.0   2.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   4.0
1   2.0   3.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2   0.0   1.0   3.0   1.0   2.0   0.0   0.0   2.0   0.0
3   1.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   2.0   0.0
4   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   2.0   3.0   0.0   0.0
5   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
```

`df.value_counts()` parece funcionar diferente en DataFrame. Apply lo aplica a cada Serie por separado.

---

**Edito por reinterpretación de pregunta**

A partir de la matriz de salida puedes filtrar valores con condiciones `bool`, definiendo:

```
data= # matriz de salida que se muestra en la pregunta
```

puedes emplear `temp=data[data>0].astype('float')` u otra condición para obtener los datos que tienen calificación entre 1 y 5, generando:

```
user    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   1   NaN 1   2   2.0 5.0 NaN 4   3   5.0
1   2   1.0 5   3   NaN 2.0 3.0 4   3   NaN
2   3   1.0 1   2   NaN 2.0 4.0 4   5   NaN
3   4   3.0 2   2   3.0 NaN 1.0 3   2   NaN
4   5   5.0 1   5   5.0 4.0 4.0 5   2   NaN
```

Luego puedes obtener las calificaciones de interés con:

```
result=temp.apply(lambda x: x[x.notna()].to_dict(), axis=1)
```

Resultando en una Serie que solo contiene las calificaciones de los items calificados:

```
user
1    {'item2': 1.0, 'item3': 2.0, 'item4': 2.0, 'it...
2    {'item1': 1.0, 'item2': 5.0, 'item3': 3.0, 'it...
3    {'item1': 1.0, 'item2': 1.0, 'item3': 2.0, 'it...
4    {'item1': 3.0, 'item2': 2.0, 'item3': 2.0, 'it...
5    {'item1': 5.0, 'item2': 1.0, 'item3': 5.0, 'it...
```

Basado en [esta otra respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38884502/13636459) en el uso de `pd.Serie.between()`, se puede poner condición de rango entre 1 y 5, reduciendo a:

```
result=data.apply(lambda x: x[x.between(1,5)].to_dict(), axis=1)
```

Comment: Me podrías ayudar por favor

Comment: La pregunta no es muy clara, creo que la información inicial que publicas no corresponde a la pregunta actual sino a un proceso anterior. He editado la respuesta según una reinterpretación del texto.
Sería bueno que agregaras que salida esperas obtener al resolver la pregunta que has hecho.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es sumar el total de cada columna te puedes ayudar del método `sum()` el cual se encarga de sumar los datos en un *DataFrame*, pero tendremos que especificar el parámetro `axis`, el cual indica en base a qué lo hará, el 0 es por columnas y el 1 es por filas.

```py
#replicando tu dataframe
cols = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
data = [                           
[0,1,2,2,5,0,4,3,5],
[1,5,3,0,2,3,4,3,0],
[1,1,2,0,2,4,4,5,0],
[3,2,2,3,0,1,3,2,0],
[5,1,5,5,4,4,5,2,0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)

#sumando
df_sum = df.sum(axis=1).to_dict()
print(df_sum)
```

Si lo que quieres específicamente es recorrer el *DataFrame* lo conveniente es usar el método `apply()` como primer parámetro recibe una función y también le debes especificar el `axis`, ejemplo.

```py
df_suma = df.apply(lambda x: sum(x), axis=1).to_dict()
```

Aquí como primer parámetro le pasas una función anónima o *lambda function* que indica que por cada columna aplicará la función `sum()` (nativa de python) y luego convierte el resultado a un diccionario.

Comment: No es precisamente lo que busco lo que quiero es esto:
dt = pd.DataFrame(rating_matrix)
   print(dt)
 print(dt[1].value_counts().to_dict())
y como resultado obtengo esto
{1: 2, 0: 1, 3: 1, 5: 1}
Más o menos quiero saber cuantas veces han votado ahí me está contando pero solo en la posición 1 de la matriz. :(

Comment: hubiera sido más sencillo si hubieras puesto en la pregunta el resultado esperado, en un momento edito mi respuesta

Comment: de igual forma confunde mucho, podrías cambiar el nombre de las columnas para mayor claridad?

Comment: print('Column', dt.columns)
print('Index', dt.index)
Salida:
Column Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype='int64', name='item')
Index Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype='int64', name='user')
Estas son mis columnas y el index

Comment: entonces solo cambia el `axis` a `axis=1` y luego llamas al método `to_dict()` y con eso bastará

Comment: Me podrías ayudar con el  ejemplo por favor

Comment: he editado la respuesta

Comment: Pero como lo puedo hacer para obtener para cada columna porque ahora lo aplica a todo a la vez :/

Comment: entonces lo que necesitas es transformar tu DataFrame a un diccionario, no recorrerlo. Eso lo haces con `df.to_dict()`

Comment: Como puedo explicarte mejor habrá la posibilidad de comunicarnos por favor

Comment: lastimosamente no tienes reputación para entrar al chat, hablaré con un moderador para ver que puede hacer, de lo contrario veré otra forma

Comment: Por favor estoy atorado días en esto porfa dame un manito :( .

Comment: pues habrá que esperar un rato, seguro @gbianchi esta durmiendo :/

Comment: Si tengo te paso el usuario o como?